# Table not showing properly [misplaced `\noalign` error]

Tags: tables

- The code below is showing a **misplaced `\noalign` error** but I can't
  figure out what is wrong.
- The table doesn't seem to display the
  `\hline` properly either.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\Large

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}m{0.12\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.13\textwidth}|>{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth}|}

    \hline

    Hi & Peach & Apple & Total\\

    \hline

    Cost & v & b & a\\

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead of `>{\centering}m{...}` you should write `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{...}`

Comment: @GAT something like the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer. Cause of problems is missing `\arraybackslash` which restore meaning of `\\`, which is overwritten by modifying `m` column type with option `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{0.12\textwidth}|C{0.13\textwidth}|C{0.20\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    Hi & Peach & Apple & Total\\
    \hline
    Cost & v & b & a\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using modifying options determined in the `ragged2e` package, `\arraybackslash` is not needed. Column `m` you can modified as follows:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
```

Further option is not to use `\\` as row terminator but `\tabularnewline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{0.12\textwidth}|C{0.13\textwidth}|C{0.20\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    Hi & Peach & Apple & Total  \tabularnewline
    \hline
    Cost & v    & b     & a     \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
    \Large
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{
                cccc
            }
\toprule
            Hi & Peach & Apple & \makecell{Total\\Cost}\\\midrule
            v & b & a &\\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```